# JavaScript checker for HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know what that script was called that checks for HTML5 and CSS3 support? I think it also adds support for them. It was called something like Modifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you looking for [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)?